# Delete all data from datatable (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have View where I have list of emails

I need to delete all data from table by button click.

I mean, can I do this on back-end by linq query  for example

How I can do this?

I know that this is to broad question, so don't minusing it

Comment: I should show some code and effort before you get downvoted!

Comment: *I know that this is to broad question, so don't minusing it* - If you know it is a broad question then narrow it down

Comment: you can use the Linq to sql query in c# to select all the records in a table and delete data of table.

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Comment: I don't have code, I just ask, how I can do this. @Izzy

Comment: Do you know write linq query or no ,if don't know i can help you to write this.

Comment: What kind of Data Access are you using, and which database? Please give us more information.  
For instance: you can use [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql](truncate table) for SQL

Comment: I think it can be done like this `var rows = db.InvitationMails.Select(myrow => myrow.Interview);` for example @FerasAlSous

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to achieve is to clear the contents of the `DataGrid` just use these methods, and either link them to a  button as below.

```
yourDataGrid.Rows.Clear()
yourDataGrid.Refresh();
```

But in all fairness you should at least add something for others to look at and not 'Write your Code' for you. Always do some research prior to asking questions, as this is the only way you will effectively learn. Hope this helps .

Comment: The question is about asp.net-mvc, not web forms (there are no events in mvc)

Comment: Sorry, however the question was very vague and I gave my interperation of it at the time before his question was edited. I have now updated my answer to remove the event.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Posted another response to this question

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete all records from the database using LINQ to SQL follow the below snippet, which will delete all records from a table:

```
context.Entities.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dt.Entities);
```

You must do this for all of your tables, as it wont be possible to just issue one command to do this. However it may be also quicker to drop and create the tables in the database again. Please refer to these pages for more info regarding the matter

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx
- https://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyzhao/linq-to-sql-extension-batch-deletion-by-lambda-expression
- http://www.telerik.com/blogs/bulk-update-and-delete-as-easy-as-linq

Answer (score 0):

```
var _data = db.tablename.Where(x => codition ).ToList();
_data.ForEach(x =>
{
    db.Entry(x).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
});
db.SaveChanges();
```